# MVVM WPF Datagrid SelectedValue bind by view model?

Tags: wpf

Anyone knows how to change the SelectedValue of the datagrid by ViewModel.If we change View then It will fire VM but not vise versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public ViewModel()
    {
        PriceLogs = new ObservableCollection<PriceLog>();

        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), Price = 200 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20), Price = 200 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(50), Price = 200 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(80), Price = 600 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(80), Price = 300 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), Price = 200 });
        //Here is how you can change selected Item from ViewModel
        SelectedPriceProlog = PriceLogs.Last();
       // SelectedPriceProlog = PriceLogs[2];
  }
    public ObservableCollection<PriceLog> PriceLogs { get; set; }

    private PriceLog selectedPriceProlog;
    public PriceLog SelectedPriceProlog 
    {
        get { return selectedPriceProlog; }

        set
        {
            selectedPriceProlog = value;
            Notify("SelectedPriceProlog");
        }
    }

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PriceLogs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPriceProlog, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

How to set Selected Value

```
    public ViewModel()
    {
        PriceLogs = new ObservableCollection<PriceLog>();

        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), Price = 200 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20), Price = 200 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(50), Price = 200 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(80), Price = 600 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(80), Price = 900 });
        PriceLogs.Add(new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), Price = 200 });
        //Here is how you can change selected value from ViewModel
        SelectedPrice = 900;
       // SelectedPriceProlog = PriceLogs[2];

        //Or ypu can set 
  }
    public ObservableCollection<PriceLog> PriceLogs { get; set; }


    private int selectedPrice ;
    public int SelectedPrice 
    {
        get { return SelectedPrice ; }

        set
        {
            selectedPrice = value;
            Notify("SelectedPriceProlog");
        }
    }

 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PriceLogs}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPrice, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Price">
```

You can do it by binding SelectedItem property of DataGrid to ViewModel Property that must be of type that your DataGrids ItemSource and binding must be TwoWay and then you can set that property in VewModel to any of the item of your collection.Or you can do it with SelectedValue as i shown above .**Now if you want to change from View to ViewModel Only then your binding Mode must be OneWay** .I hope this will help.

Comment: SelectedPrice = 900;
       // SelectedPriceProlog = PriceLogs[2];
do you know how to equal 
SelectedPriceProlog to new instance of PriceLog ?
then it will not point to selecteded row
hOW I did that by looping though the collection 
and match each property do you know how to optimeze this.
Great thanks.

Comment: In your question you ask you want to update from view to VM nt vice versa. Without looping the collection.... for that case you bind SelectedPrice to SelectedValue of Datagrid and Give Price as SelectedValuePath then Set SelectedPrice to the Price of your new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a DataBinding that updates the ViewModel but not vise versa so, there is a DataBinding mode called `OneWayToSource` for  ex :
 `<TextBox Text="{Binding TextProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>`

Comment: I think you didnt get my question properly.I need to change the selected row change in datagrid by ViewModel.give a try as following change the selected row as viewmodel need to change it when page loading.

Comment: SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedBTTerm, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" is my code.

Comment: ***If we change View then It will fire VM but not vise versa*** Very misleading. here wants to say that updates are originally made at the View.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions.

- Each VM which stands as an item of the DataGrids's collection can
  implement `IsSelected` property. Then you should adjust bindings and
  notify parent VM to update its property `SelectedItem` or
  `SelectedItems`
- We wanted `SelectedItems` to work in both directions (VM -> V and V
  -> VM) without the need to declare `IsSelected` property for the items.
   I've coded static class SelectionHelper with several
  attached properties. One of these properties accepts collection of
  items and keeps DataGrid.SelectedItems in sync with it. Thus we can
  contol selections from the VM.
   Another property is of type
  `ICommand`. And this command is executed every time selection is
  changed by user actions. The parameter of the command is
  DataGrid.SelectedItems collection.
   Now I planned the support of
  direct manipulation of the bound collection instead of executing the
  command.

If you need I can share the code when come to the office tomorrow.